# Decode extrinsic on substrate side

Tags: extrinsic, rpc, json-rpc

hello is there a way to decode this kind of extrinsic on substrate side without polkadotJs :

> extrinsics: [0402000b935b2a697f01,
> 84003c2eb55ba53099bea9031b4a30c9a553c29f7c4a3a9f266d6208954268aa8825014031ae12b4edb8b6f49e407b88f21022460e523d57337b70a46ce23765d4b645cd4f05fefaf77be348994429492d1c923ce1a3bbe00a5397e809fbac72864d8dc5031000050000d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d02093d00]

?

I think that `0402000b935b2a697f01` is "set timestamp" for example.

Comment: Which network is it for by the way? What is genesis hash?

Comment: we use our own substrate blockchain, genesis hash is 0x7253b2c4dcbdd53e3aae5372006d4bcd8a587428ad8f487ddfa116ca2b6d8d9f

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all the information you need to decode those extrinsic blobs can be found using the Runtime Metadata.

The first two bytes of any extrinsic will tell you which pallet and call is being made:

```
vv pallet
0402000b935b2a697f01
  ^^ call
```

So you want to look at your runtime metadata, and find which pallet is the 4th index (the 5th pallet), and which call is the 2nd index (the 3rd call).

I think in this case that this is NOT the timestamp set call, since timestamp only has 1 extrinsic, so the call index would never be `02`.

Comment: ok thank you, and how to know how much args do we have for example in this case `{
        isSigned: true
        method: {
          args: {
            dest: {
              Id: 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
            }
            value: 1.0000 µUnit
          }
          method: transfer
          section: balances
        }`

Comment: That is also in the metadata, each call will have a list of the arguments it expects, and the datatype that it expects.

Comment: ok but  for example this extrinsic : 84003c2eb55ba53099bea9031b4a30c9a553c29f7c4a3a9f266d6208954268aa8825014031ae12b4edb8b6f49e407b88f21022460e523d57337b70a46ce23765d4b645cd4f05fefaf77be348994429492d1c923ce1a3bbe00a5397e809fbac72864d8dc5031000050000d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d02093d00 is a balance transfer I guess but how can I know the number of bytes for each arg?

Comment: Yes, that is also information which is conveyed in the metadata. Unfortunately it is not something that has an easy answer, you probably need a library to help you parse the metadata and get all this information, which is what Polkadot JS API is doing.

Comment: Yes but I need to do that in substrate side :-)

Comment: Can you add more context to your question? Why are you parsing this on "substrate" side. Maybe you should ask a second question with more information

Comment: yes sorry, because we need to be able to return json format from the node directly. is it possible to give me the example how to decode this one : 84003c2eb55ba53099bea9031b4a30c9a553c29f7c4a3a9f266d6208954268aa8825014031ae12b4edb8b6f49e407b88f21022460e523d57337b70a46ce23765d4b645cd4f05fefaf77be348994429492d1c923ce1a3bbe00a5397e809fbac72864d8dc5031000050000d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d02093d00 ? thank you

Comment: Please see here how Parity Signer does this:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity-signer/tree/master/rust/parser

Comment: hum thank you but how can I decode 84003c2eb55ba53099bea9031b4a30c9a553c29f7c4a3a9f266d6208954268aa8825014031ae12b4edb8b6f49e407b88f21022460e523d57337b70a46ce23765d4b645cd4f05fefaf77be348994429492d1c923ce1a3bbe00a5397e809fbac72864d8dc5031000050000d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d02093d00 with Parity Signer ?

Comment: You need to convert this line to Vec<u8> and pass it to https://github.com/paritytech/parity-signer/blob/02a7b00789698c3ab3ed65b83bc1a77f18b88071/rust/parser/src/lib.rs#L28 - as you can see, that function also requires other information, that is, metadata and some extra network specs. Feel free to use this function (I'll certainly publish this crate after formatting it properly) or just study how it works - essentially it consumes method vector sequentially checking for exact formatting in metadata. I'll try to post my cowboy's notes on how to decode that manually later unless I forget to.

Comment: Ok sounds great thank you. what should be metadata here?

Comment: It is a struct that describes whether it is legacy or V14+ metadata: https://github.com/varovainen/parity-signer/blob/38fefb1157809f3df628a800e433fc40aea4f89e/rust/parser/src/lib.rs#L188

If it is V14, it indeed contains substrate metadata object from frame_metadata

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi 0402000b935b2a697f01 is decoded even with polkadot ui as  {
  isSigned: false,
  method: {
    args: { now: '1,646,736,858,003' },
    method: 'set',
    section: 'timestamp'
  }
My metadata are in V12 maybe it can be because of that?

Comment: v12 metadata would be "Legacy", right? So that would change how you construct the metadata struct (As per Alexander's answer)

Comment: I tried : to get the extrinsic with polkadot api `ex.toHex()` give me  `0x280402000bd77af29b7f01`
and `ex.toHuman()` gives me `{
  isSigned: false,
  method: {
    args: { now: '1,647,588,834,007' },
    method: 'set',
    section: 'timestamp'
  }
}` I dont understand why set timestamp is relative to 0402

Comment: It would help greatly if you post your metadata somewhere.

The pallet with 1 call could have call indices above 1, because - unless TX version or some parameter with similar idea is bumped - to keep backwards compatibility, deprecated call indices are kept on update. So if there were other calls in this pallet that were removed later or changed so that their parameters are not compatible, you can get index 2. But to figure this out, you need metadata.

Comment: please find my metadata here : https://textdoc.co/3G68nuxD9sd7VfAj

Answer (score 0):

If your chain is running metadata version v14 or above you can use Libuptest:

```rust
use libuptest::decode_extrinsic::decode_extrinsic_hex_string;
use libuptest::jsonrpseeclient::JsonrpseeClient;
use libuptest::ws_mod::get_raw_metadata;


let raw_extrinsic = "input my hex string here";
let metadata: Vec<u8> = get_raw_metadata(JsonrpseeClient::polkadot_default_url().unwrap())
        .await?; 
let decoded_output = decode_extrinsic_hex_string(raw_extrinsic, &metadata);
println!("The decoded output is: {:?}", decoded_output);
```

https://github.com/uptest-sc/uptest/blob/main/examples/examples/decode_extrinsics.rs